# Custom Audio control for audio player

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Any heads up or direction how to link a custom audio player control to your audio player playlist?
Markup for my player is this

```
<div id="fullcontainer">
     <audio src="" controls id="Player"></audio>
 <!-- my playlist starts here -->                     

  <ul id="playlist" style="">
    <li class="now-playing" style=""><a href="audio.mp3"></li>          
    <li><a href="audio2.mp3">title</a></li>                 
    <li><a href="audio2.mp3">title</a></li>     
  </ul>
```

There are some java scripts there and a function calls up the Player

```
<script> //calls the player       
    audioPlayer();      
</script>
```

I had a nice custom audio controls from a friend , How do i repplace the default audio controls with this one??.

```
<div class="audio-player">
<div id="play-btn"></div>
<div class="audio-wrapper" id="player-container" href="javascript:;">
 <audio id="audioPlayer" ontimeupdate="initProgressBar()">
  <source src="" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
</div>  

<div class="player-controls scrubber">

  <span id="seekObjContainer">
          <progress id="seekObj" value="0" max="1"></progress>
        </span>
</div>
```

I just need the steps and a few lines of java then i can be able to improvise from there.
Any direction how to go about this?

Comment: remove the `controls` attrribute from the audio element. now place your markup. some javascript to bind the elements of the controls markup to the player functions. Where is your problem? Where do you struggle?

Comment: @joshua k 4,  I could get the seek progress bar to work properly but the cover image do not change with the new track,

Comment: Then you need to write some code that do what you want and add the track titles to the markup... I know: should be obvious, but you didn't do it. so please try it and show some code if it's not working.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just replace the controls? You write your own markup and use JavaScript to control the audio.

Comment: This is wjhat i am trying to adapt to a playlist.                      https://codepen.io/luke__duncan/pen/dpZVOr     T^he playlist actually works for me just that the cover picture for each track doesnt show and the track title doesnt as well. Apaert fro that, every thing proceeds to next song, progress bar, and all time updates.